# Use AudioTrack with AudioManager setSpeakerphoneOn

Tags: android, audiotrack, android-audiomanager

I am using AudioTrack to play the sound I recieve through UDP sockets. I am getting a lot of noise along with the sound so I decided to use AudioManager. But AudioManager changes sound routing beyond the bounds of the application. Below is the code I am using.

```
        m_amAudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
        m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

The problem with this code is that when I close the app and start a Music Player, the sound comes from the front speaker and not the ususal back speaker and I cannot change it somehow. 
To resolve this issue I decided to add the following line when I am closing my app.

```
 m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

But with this line the problem is that when I recieve a call (normal call), by default the speaker is turned on. I really need help on this please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you will need to declare the User permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS in you manifest to change the AudioManager settings.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

1. Before you change any settings, you must save the current AudioManager settings!

   ```
   oldAudioMode = audioManager.getMode();
   oldRingerMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();
   isSpeakerPhoneOn = audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
   ```
2. Apply your Audio settings (Example)

   ```
   audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
   audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
   audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
   ```
3. Then on finish, restore the settings

   ```
   audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(isSpeakerPhoneOn);
   audioManager.setMode(oldAudioMode);
   audioManager.setRingerMode(oldRingerMode);
   ```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. I have used this permission. And did fix one of my problems. Speaker is no longer on by default. But with this code I tried to run the music player and it started running on the front speaker. Any idea how to change that to default?

Comment: The default is the one set by the user of the Device before he starts your app. The point is to restore the AudioManager Setting to the state is was in before you changing it. So if speakerPhone is off before your app starts, it will be off when your app stops.

Comment: @hsigmond is it OK if we change mode after AudioTrack is started ?

Answer (score 1):

Set this when closing the app.

m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);